# Spring boot upgrade to 1.2.0+ seems to break the log4j2 compatibility and other things?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that uses log4j2 (like so: [Changing JHipster to use log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872859/changing-jhipster-to-use-log4j2)) .  I was one Spring boot 1.2.0.M2.

Once I upgrade to 1.2.0 (or 1.2.1) release.  It looks like logging isn't working properly with 
gradle bootRun  (or grade run)

I see the following in my output  Which looks like there is an issue with Hazecast that needs an update Is that how you'd read the rest of the errors?

For the logging is it just not picking up the log4j2 xml file anymore and I need to put it in a different location?

UPDATE:  I resolved the exceptions ... here is the updated output of the spring boot application:

```
${LOG_PATTERN}:app:findMainClass
:app:run
${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_
PATTERN}
${LOG_PATTERN}
${LOG_PATTERN}                                                                                                    ${LOG_PATTERN}
${LOG_PATTERN}
${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}
${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}
${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}
```

As you can see.  No exceptions yet logging is not working properly
Any thoughts about how I could debug?

**OLD OUTPUT PLEASE IGNORE:** 
ouput:

```
${LOG_PATTERN}:app:findMainClass
:app:run
${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}
${LOG_PATTERN}
${LOG_PATTERN} 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.init(WebFilter.java:118) ~[hazelcast-wm-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4615) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5222) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_25]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_25]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_25]
                                                                                                                                                             $
{LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}${LOG_PATTERN}
${LOG_PATTERN}
${LOG_PATTERN}
${LOG_PATTERN} org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewControllerHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'viewControllerHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:602) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) [spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at main(Application.java:82) [main/:?]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'viewControllerHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resources may not be accessed if they are not currently started
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.validate(StandardRoot.java:245) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:212) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResource(ApplicationContext.java:533) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResource(ApplicationContextFacade.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.exists(ServletContextResource.java:102) ~[spring-web-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.addStaticIndexHtmlViewControllers(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:273) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.addViewControllers(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:268) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.addViewControllers(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:119) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.addViewControllers(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:75) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.viewControllerHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:346) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6be536e2.CGLIB$viewControllerHandlerMapping$30(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6be536e2$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2c3a8301.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6be536e2.viewControllerHandlerMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:591) ~[spring-beans-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar:4.1.3.RELEASE]
        ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the 3.2.5 code an your stacktrace, it goes wrong at the last line of this code fragment:

```
public final void init(final FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    filterConfig = config;
    servletContext = config.getServletContext();
    initInstance();
    String mapName = getParam("map-name");
    if (mapName != null) {
        clusterMapName = mapName;
    } else {
        clusterMapName = "_web_" + servletContext.getServletContextName();
    }
    try {
        Config hzConfig = hazelcastInstance.getConfig();<<----------
```

Can you post some additional logging, because apparently the HZ instance has not been created.

How are you configuring log4j2 for HZ? HZ 3.2.5 has no support for log4j2. I believe that is added in 3.3. Perhaps HZ is failing because the logger failed to be created?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I've managed to resolve the exceptions however the logging is still not reporting properly throughout the whole app.   I believe the Hazelcast stuff was a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here was my log4j2.xml file.  Setting a LOG_PATTERN variable used to work and now I had to remove that variable.

this gits:
https://gist.github.com/hooligan495/c321f98f6c8f5338f726

Shows the old and new.